# Don't know why I am getting StopIteration error

Tags: python, generator, stopiteration

I am writing a program that takes in input from a file and each line may contain "ATG" or "GTG" and I am pretty sure I have done everything right as far as what I am trying to do. IT is my first time using a generator in python and after researching this problem I still don't Know why I am getting stop iteration. For this, my generator must yield a tuple with the start locations for either ATG or GTG found in each string.

```
import sys

import p3mod


gen = p3mod.find_start_positions()
gen.send(None)   # prime the generator

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        (seqid,seq) = line.strip().lower().split()
        slocs = gen.send(seq)
        print(seqid,slocs,"\n")

gen.close()  ## added to be more official
```

This is the generator

```
def find_start_positions (DNAstr = ""):

    DNAstr = DNAstr.upper()

    retVal = ()
    x = 0
    loc = -1

    locations = []

    while (x + 3) < len(DNAstr):

        if (DNAst[x:x+3] is "ATG" or DNAstr[x:x+3] is "GTG" ):
            loc = x

        if loc is not -1:
            locations.append(loc)

        loc = -1

    yield (tuple(locations))
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p3rmb.py", line 12, in <module>
    slocs = gen.send(seq)
StopIteration
```

Comment: is there a traceback printed out showing each line?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):File "p3rmb.py", line 12, in <module>
    slocs = gen.send(seq)
StopIteration

Comment: If you're calling `send`, `yield` needs to be assigned to a value.

Comment: @TylerDunn I'm having difficulty understanding what you are trying to accomplish with a coroutine here...

Comment: As an aside, don't use `is` to compare strings. That isn't what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a generator that returns all the data at once.
You should yield the data in each iteration. This code might not be perfect, but it might solve part of your problem:

```
def find_start_positions (DNAstr = ""):
    DNAstr = DNAstr.upper()

    x = 0
    loc = -1

    while x + 3 < len(DNAstr):
        if DNAst[x:x+3] == "ATG" or DNAstr[x:x+3] == "GTG" :
            loc = x

        if loc is not -1:
            yield loc

        loc = -1
```

The StopIteration isn't an error. It's the way a generator signalizes that it exhausted all of it's data. You just need to "try except" it or use your generator in a forloop that already does that for you.
Despite they aren't THAT complicated, it may take some time to get used to these "weird" errors. ;)

Comment: Don't use `is` to compare strings.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sure man! Haven't noticed that, focused completely in the generator stuff. Thank you!

Comment: Is the variaable DNAstr changed everytime gen.send() is used in the main function?

Comment: Also do I need to clear out the lists and stuff after every yield?

Comment: @TylerDunn The variable is changed only inside the method because immutable arguments like strings, integers and tuples are passed by value not by reference. So the changes you do are discarded.
Not necessarily. It's good to use the less resources and variables as possible, but it's not mandatory. But if you clear wrong stuff, the generator may present some weird behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Your generator is built to return only one value in its entire lifetime.  It iterates through the `while` loop, finds all of the `locations`, and returns that entire list in one fell swoop.  Thus, when you call `send` a second time, you have exhausted the generator's operations.

You need to figure out what you expect from each invocation of `send`; configure your loop to produce just that much, and then `yield` that result ... and keep doing that for future `send` invocations.  Your `yield` statement has to be inside a loop for this to work.

**Jayme** gave you an excellent example in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in [find()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm) function to find a substring in a given string. Is a generator really necessary here?

Instead, you could try:

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    text = f.read()

for i, my_string in enumerate(text.strip().lower().split()):
    atg_index = my_string.find('atg')
    gtg_index = my_string.find('gtg')
    print(i, atg_index, gtg_index, my_string)
```

Comment: I wish but it is an assignment

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_start_positions (DNAstr = ""):
    DNAstr = DNAstr.upper()

    x = 0
    loc = -1

    while x + 3 < len(DNAstr):
        if DNAst[x:x+3] == "ATG" or DNAstr[x:x+3] == "GTG" :
            loc = x

        if loc is not -1:
            yield loc

        loc = -1
```